# Does Vue 3 + Inertia remove event listeners automatically when component is unmounted?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have an event listener inside `script setup`:

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'

const elementRef = ref(null)
    
window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (!elementRef.value.contains(event.target)){
        console.log('click outside element')
    }
})

</script>


<template>
  <div ref="elementRef">your element</div>
</template>
```

Will it be removed when the component is unmounted or do I have to remove it manually?

Comment: Inertia or not, there's no possibility for a framework to know that you added global listeners without using framework-specific api, and you need to remove them yourself. Btw there's useEventListener in vueuse that handles this

Answer (score 2):

The global event listener is not automatically removed, so your component will need to explicitly do that.

You should add the listener in the `mounted` hook, and remove it in the `unmounted` hook. Also, you'll need to store the function passed to `addEventListener` so that it could be passed to `removeEventListener`:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue'

const elementRef = ref(null)

const onClick = (event) => {
    if (!elementRef.value.contains(event.target)) {
        console.log('click outside element')
    }
}

onMounted(() => window.addEventListener('click', onClick))
onUnmounted(() => window.removeEventListener('click', onClick))
</script>
```

Comment: @p0358 Pinia's `$subscribe()` likely has component hooks to unsubscribe itself. When you explicitly call `window.addEventListener`, you're managing the event listening (and un-listening) manually. Vue doesn't do it for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to automatically deregister event listeners:

```js
import { getCurrentScope, onScopeDispose } from "vue";

export function addEventListenerWrapper(target, name, fn) {
    target.addEventListener(name, fn);
    if (getCurrentScope()) {
        onScopeDispose(() => target.removeEventListener(name, fn));
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to just register your listener inside of your component like this and it should deregister later automatically:

```js
addEventListenerWrapper(window, "click", event => {
    if (!elementRef.value.contains(event.target)) {
        console.log("click outside element");
    }
})
```

[Please refer to the following Vue SFC Playground to see it in action.](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9U8GOmzAQ/RWvLxCJgHpNSdSqrdRDT+1Ke/GFhYF4a2zLNkRVxL93BocsibThgsfz5s3MG8+Zf7U2HwfgO1762kkbmIcw2IPQsrfGBXZmDlo2sdaZngmOWME/X73P4MPiyguyiG1GCF0bjd7ed2xPJGnyE5Qy7MU41TwlG8REhD+a0wUS3ADkKItYDdaBRoDeqioAWoyVx0+H83mmnaayQGu+fR1CMJp9qZWs/+4FTzdsf1ion+gv+OHZdJ2CsojgGDi3MG5li0ERVqCjLK5JecZjt9u+svmbNxrVOlOsuDi84Ds239DdLMAOD8cQrN8VhW9rUuXN58Z1BZ5yN+gge8jB99tXZ04eHBILThST0BOmXLR8MBkULGMdhG+Dc6DDn9pYyJjR8+G79NZ4uAwuQaZkNRRQ0GPIbxxtFF4PSpHwQreDroNEKaum+TEi6Jf0ATS4F1dZCy4NlcOkGdNVj+lavVlaJ2qjIFemSwV30FGgk7pjQDyCUwICRob8PkF6ZbzgZMvSu/7SzTUdfbfNpnHoK/8qm4PejPA44fLddtLAg17omxaDZkcafiTdSerGnDKWzK80yVg6s62rpp7fp5OPlcL3gvWESmof4Xns6FaJdcmRnmGAbGCZ9bxwS5Fx1Ddbdr9nuBqNHOlx4GK8V4Rb9M8MbmEtCwTd7cv0HzXneMw=) You should see in the console that toggling the element with the button will cause the console to print event registration/deregistration messages.

See these links for more info:

- https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#onscopedispose
- https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/blob/78ec9a186dcbce3d583db332ae22094a182358cc/packages/pinia/src/subscriptions.ts

Comment: Apparently VueUse provides a very similar utility func too (if you use built-in addEventListener and not some custom code): https://vueuse.org/core/useeventlistener/